# What is the accuracy of file creation time?

Tags: windows, file, synchronization

I wanna do some measurements and video recording at the same time. It is crutial that I can align them after the measurement. My idea is to get the creation time of the video in ms and than add 1/fps milliseconds for each frame and look up the measurement closest to that calculated time.

If I use C# for example and use the [CreationTime-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of the recorded video, I should be able to do this synchronisation, shouldn't I? How good is the CreationTime? I need an accuracy about 60 ms...

Comment: Creation time is only recorded in in a value which includes whole seconds, and depends on your system clock. If in fact you use FAT32, the time is only accurate to about 2 seconds. NTFS, to the second.

Answer (score 1):

File time stamps on FAT drives are rounded to the nearest two seconds (even number) when the file is written to the drive. The file time stamps on NTFS drives are rounded to the nearest 100 nanoseconds when the file is written to the drive. 
[Time Stamps Change When Copying From NTFS to FAT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/127830)

Answer (score 0):

According to this link, the creation time on FAT volumes is good down to 10 milliseconds. I can only assume that NTFS would do better, but I can't verify that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Interesting, @Mark -- I recall `rsync` documentation advising that the `modify-window` option is necessary when dealing with FAT32. Can't find the link now, but it's hinted at here: http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/appnote/14729.html